# Scala protocol buffers compiler

Tags: scala, protocol-buffers

I was thinking about writing a code generator to generate scala from google protobuf definitions file. The reason I see it valuable is the java bindings are too Java-ish and one could do much better in scala.
For example for the following definition

```
message Foo {
  required int F1 = 1;
  repeated string F2 = 2;
  message Inner (
    required int F3 = 1;
  )
}
```

I want to be able to construct the proto object from Scala like this:

```
val foo = Foo (
  F1(127),
  F2("first", "second"),
  Inner (
    F3(911)
  )
)
```

My question is if anyone knows something along these lines already existing, or if not do you find it worthy to start a new project?

Comment: I've looked for such a project, but haven't found one. Please start! You might look at http://scalaxb.org/ for inspiration. And think about the 22 element limit on case classes from the start :)

Comment: Intereseting. I had no intention to use case classes in my projections. Could you please give me a hint how they were used in scalaxb (or in some other similar situation)?

Comment: The 22 element limit means you were right not to think about case classes.  They're not useful here.

Answer (score 14):

I'm currently working on a Scala Protocol Buffers compiler with my mentor Viktor Klang. It's my Google Summer of Code project and you can follow the progress on github at https://github.com/SandroGrzicic/ScalaBuff.

[Update] The main part is complete; I still need to implement Extensions, Groups and field Options support. It's usable and I invite everyone to try it and give feedback; I'm open to suggestions and feature requests.

Comment: What is progress of your implementation? Is it already useful?

Comment: It consists of multiple parts: the main ones are Parser which recognizes input .proto files and returns a parse tree, Generator which takes that tree and generates output Scala classes, and of course the main class which handles the Parser and the Generator (and has very similar CLI functionality to protoc). The ScalaBuff and Parser parts have been completed for some time now; the Parser (should) recognize and build a tree out of any valid .proto file. The Generator currently supports generation of Messages and Enums, however I'm currently finishing that part. Stay tuned, I update it often. ;)

Comment: @SandroGržičić - might be interesting to update this answer.  Looks like there have been recent commits to the project.

Comment: @JamesMoore - Right, however it's mostly minor bug fixes and a few improvements. I still have to implement Extensions and Options support. I can't give a time estimate, however if anyone notifies me in some way to indicate that they need those features badly, I'll be sure to speed them along! :)

Comment: I've used ScalaBuff recently. +1

Answer (score 1):

There's this project that uses Simple-Build-Tool plugins to achieve that effect: http://github.com/codahale/protobuf-sbt?locale=sv

**Update:**
The above project no longer exists. The [sbt-protobuf](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-protobuf) plugin extended the functionality of that original project. Note, however, that sbt-protobuf generates Java classes, not Scala.

Comment: Doesn't it generate java bindings?

Answer (score 1):

I just came across these but can not vouch for them as I've never used them.

http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-scala/

https://github.com/jeffplaisance/scala-protobuf

Comment: **Feb 20016** All of the above links are inactive project (look below for more updated versions).

Answer (score 1):

A really good tool to generate both Scala and Java classes from .proto files is [ScalaPB](https://github.com/trueaccord/ScalaPB). The tool extends the functionality of the [sbt-protobuf](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-protobuf) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be possible to write a Scala compiler plugin that read and compiled .proto files?

Comment: It could be a proto compiler for scala. Open sourced Google code has backends for various programming languages.